# Selecting Map Points Inside a Map Poly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coordinates, geospatial

I'm trying to find an algorithmic way to select which points fall within a specific arbitrarily shaped area on a Google Map. Basically I want to be able to provide a point and ask a function if that point lies within an arbitrary (but specifically defined) map area.

For example, how could I tell if a point was contained within the green section (Brions Regional Park) on the follow map:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&q=state+park&fb=1&gl=us&ei=Rm-tTIGRBI2jnQeXrZyTBg&ved=0CEoQtgMwAw&sll=37.912242,-122.078705&sspn=0.086,0.17355&split=1&rq=1&ev=zi&radius=5.68&hq=state+park&hnear=&ll=37.934585,-122.13192&spn=0.089358,0.17355&z=13
```

I need help figuring out how to define the specific area and also then the algorithm that would take in the defined area & point and return true/false.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been helpful for me:

https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Comment: You may wish to read up on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers about link-only answers.  Posting more information in your post would be helpful.